# Adjusting screen colors using Python

Tags: python

Is there any way to adjust screen colors using Python? I need to saturate the screen a bit.
I need it only on Windows.
If there is any library that is able to do it please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Why ‘saturate’ the screen on Win only.  Is this to make the console colours appear more vividly?